# jQuery filter items based on anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, show-hide

I have a **four `a` tags** that I would like to use filter *(hide & show)* my content.

What is the best approach given the HTML that I am working with? I have tried to achieve this myself but my jQuery is often repetitive and doesn't work.

**Scenario**

1. All four content sections are shown by default
2. Selecting an anchor tag will show the relevant content and hide the other 3
3. **Selecting an anchor tag twice will show all content (step 1)**

```html
<div class="left mob-filter">
  <a href="#" class="filter m-performance" data-filter="1">Performance</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter m-music" data-filter="2">Music</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter m-art" data-filter="3">Art</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter m-food" data-filter="4">Food</a>
</div>

<div class="m-performance"><p>Performance Content</p></div>
<div class="m-music"><p>Performance Content</p></div>
<div class="m-art"><p>Performance Content</p></div>
<div class="m-food" ><p>Performance Content</p></div>
```

Comment: Can you change the HTML at all?  You've said "given the HTML" but there are better approaches (linking link+div with a data- attribute rather than the same class for example) (i.e add data-filter="1" to your m-performance div)

Answer (score 3):

With some modification on your html this is what you want;

```js
$(function() {

  $("a.filter").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(this);
    $("div.content div").hide(); //hide all
    $("div.content div." + a.data("filter")).show(); //show clicked
  });

  $("a.filter").on("dblclick", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.content div").show(); //show all
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left mob-filter">
  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="m-performance">Performance</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="m-music">Music</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="m-art">Art</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="m-food">Food</a>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="m-performance">
    <p>Performance Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m-music">
    <p>Music Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m-art">
    <p>Art Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="m-food">
    <p>Food Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great however does not allow me de-select a filter, or add multiple filters. I think I will go with a vanilla JS approach that works with the `input` element.

Comment: double click on any a tag will deselect filter, what do you mean to add multiple filters?

Answer (score 0):

Use ids on the a tag and with jQuery call the id.click(function(){
Do show/hide code here!
})

Comment: Change a for button and put an id on each button unique like <button id="performance">performance</button> then in javascript use jQuery like this $("#performance").click(function(){$(".m-music).css("display","none"}); repeat for others

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar thing before and what i did was not using hrefs but instead 4 buttons. Each with an onclick behaviour and in that onclick you could target different div's with their id's like you have done above and do things like showing content or hiding it. But you could do similar with the a tags as well.

Comment: Do you have an example - on JSFiddle perhaps?